# Linux executable parameters tab complete

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu. For many executables (i.e. valgrind) you can start typing a parameter like `--leak-check=full` and tab-complete it by the time you type `--le`

I recently added `--version` parameter to my own program (in c++).

**Question**: How can I add this functionality of tab-completion of arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define that in `/etc/bash_completion` (**edit:** and `/etc/bash_completion.d/`).

Have a look at this article: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316

Comment: Although related to my question, this isn't the exact solution. For example valgrind doesn't use it. Also, does this mean that when I distribute my software I have to tell users to modify their bash_completion file?

Comment: @Mikhail: You would let the installer drop a file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/316) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of the shell (I believe the default for Ubuntu is still bash) you are using, not your program.